# Categorías y sub categorías - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, laravel, laravel-blade

Tengo dos tablas, categorias y sub_categorias

```
categorias:               |     sub_categorias
id  | descripcion         |    id  | id_categoria | descripcion
====|============         |   =====|==============|=============
 1  | Estudiantes         |    1   |   1          | Cuadernos 
 2  | Tecnologias         |    2   |   1          | Libros
                          |    1   |   2          | Computadoras  
                          |    3   |   1          | Lapiceros
```

Estuve intentando de muchas maneras el como guardarlo según a la categoría que corresponda e iniciar el desde 1 según a la categoría que corresponda e ir incrementándolo según se creen datos.

Comment: Tu problema segun entiendo parece ser en tu base de datos, tienes que establecer el id como AUTO_INCREMENT para que se incremente en 1 por cada registro

Comment: Sii, ese es mi principal problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues puedes hacer esto en tu método create

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
       // $codigo = new Codigo();
        $categorias = DB::table('sub_categorias')
                        ->select('id_generado', DB::raw('max(id_generado) as id_generado'))
                        ->where('categoria_id',$request->categoria_id)->first();
        if ($categorias->id_generado ==0) {
            $_id_generado = '01';
        }elseif($categorias->id_generado>0){
            $id_generado = $categorias->id_generado+1;
            $_id_generado = '0'.$id_generado;
        }else{
            $_id_generado = $categorias->id_generado+1;
        }

        dd("El mayor de la categoria ".$request->categoria_id.' es: '.$categorias->id_generado. ' ESTO SERIA EL ID GENERADO: ' .$_id_generado);
    }
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Gracias me ayudó y me genera el código que deseo!

Answer (score 1):

Al momento de crear la tabla establece el id como AUTO_INCREMENT, ejemplo

```
create table categorias(
 id int(16) auto_increment, 
 descripcion text,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

)

en caso uses phpmyadmin tienes que seleccionar el check de A_I [image: Ejemplo]

Comment: Si eso está bien pero lo que quiero hacer es la parte de la lógica, el como verificar a cual le pertenece ya que en el store obtengo el id de la categoria pero despues no sé...

Answer (score 0):

La manera optima con laravel es creando la migración:

`php artisan make:model Categorias -m`

el comando `-m` creara una migración, te diriges hacia ella (que deberia de ser algo así: `2017_02_01_124532_create_categorias_table.php` en la carpeta `database->migrations`), veras 2 funciones `up()` y `down()` para indicar el autoincremental te importa el  `up()` crearas algo asi:

```
Schema::create('categorias', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id'); //este es el autoincremental, laravel asi lo indica en la base de datos.
    $table->string('descripcion');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Crearas el segundo modelo `subcategorias` de la siguiente manera:

`php artisan make:model Subcategorias -m`

Ubicas la migración de la misma manera que ubicaste la anterior.

```
Schema::create('subcategorias', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('nombre');
    $table->string('descripcion');
    $table->integer('id_categoria');
    $table->foreign('id_categoria')->references('id')->on('categorias');
    $table->boolean('status');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Lo siguiente a ejecutar es un par de comandos:

`php artisan migrate:rollback` este para eliminar la base de datos

`php artisan migrate` este para crear de nuevo la base de datos

Espero haberte ayudado. Cualquier duda déjalo en los comentarios.