# ¿Cómo desplegar lista jerárquica con Laravel-VueJS?

Tags: mysql, laravel, vuejs

Tengo una tabla de categorías con esta estructura:

```
+-----------------------------------+
| id |   nombre         | parent_id |
+-----------------------------------+
|   1| categoria1       | null      |
|   2| categoria2       | null      |
|   3| subcategoria1    | 1         |
|   4| subcategoria2    | 2         |
|   5| subsubcategoria2 | 4         |
|   6| categoria3       | null      |
+-----------------------------------+
```

¿De qué manera puedo desplegarlo como una lista jerárquica utilizando Laravel y VueJS? Necesito un resultado similar a éste:

```
-categoria1
  -subcategoria1
-categoria2
  -subcategoria2
    -subsubcategoria2
-categoria3
```

Comment: Esta pregunta ya la hizo un usuario, echale un ojo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/47188/categor%C3%ADas-y-sub-categor%C3%ADas-laravel

Comment: Mi problema es diferente, necesito desplegar en una vista los datos de la tabla en la forma que describí.

Comment: Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow en español. Con Vue podés iterar con `v-for`. Cuál es el problema concretamente? Muéstranos que tienes hecho: cómo haces la consulta a BD, cómo obtienes esos datos desde la vista y como intentaste mostrarlos. Te sugiero leer [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida.. Luego presiona en [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/315715/edit) y agrega un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de tu código para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Tuviste alguna solucion? Para la lista jerarquica